# Linking an external pre-built library in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I am building a project that utilizes a library that is outside of the scope of the project. I am relatively new to CMake and I can't seem to get this library to build. my code is below:

```
    cmake_minimum_version(VERSION 3.1) 
    
    project(cameraCode VERSION 1.0.0)
    add_library(camControl SHARED IMPORTED
                /opt/MVS/lib/64/MVCamControl
                /opt/MVS/include/MvCamControl.h)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} cameraCode.cpp)
    
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                PRIVATE
                camControl)
```

when I make this, it configures okay, but when I build it, I get this error:
make[2] *** No rule to make target 'camControl-NOTFOUND', needed by 'cameraCode'. Stop.

Comment: what files are under /opt/MVS/lib/64/MVCamControl ?

Comment: that is the complete path to the .so file that I am trying to include

Comment: How can it be a "complete path to the .so file" yet not end in ".so" ? is there a `libMVCamControl.so` under that directory?

Comment: yes, that is where the .so file is located

Comment: And what is the .so file called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add_library** would mean that you are building the library.

I **don't** think add_library is what you want, if this is the prebuilt library as you say.

It looks like you just need **[link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html)** and **[include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html)** for the client to be able to find library and header files.

Comment: I just tried that and now I'm getting this:/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcamControl

Comment: You have to check the documentation for the correct syntax

Comment: this is what I have now: 
find_library(MvCamControl
            /opt/MVS/lib/64/
            /opt/MVS/include/
            REQUIRED)   
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} cameraCode.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    MvCamControl
)
MvCamControl is the name of the library and the path to the library itself is below that and the path to the header file is below that.

Answer (score 0):

You were right with the `IMPORTED` library, but you need to [set some properties](https://devdocs.io/cmake%7E3.15/command/add_library#imported-libraries) instead of passing the files as part of `add_library`:

```
add_library(camControl SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(camControl PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/MVS/lib/64/MVCamControl/libMVCamControl.so
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/MVS/include/
)
```

Comment: okay, I tried that and I am getting this error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMvCameraControl

Comment: And is there a `libMvCameraControl.so` in /opt/MVS/lib/64/MVCamControl/? Show the full linker command line with `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: This is the error I get now: No rule to make target '/opt/MVS/lib/64/libMVCameraControl.so', needed by 'cameraCode'.  Stop.

Comment: I am asking for the fifth time now: **what is the name of the .so file under '/opt/MVS/lib/64/'?**

Comment: it is MvCameraControl.so

Comment: Does your IMPORTED_LOCATION end on "/MvCameraControl.so" or "/libMvCameraControl.so" ? Also keep in mind that capitalization matters.

Comment: @StevenKraine: Under `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property you should write the absolute path of your library file. The error `No rule to make target` for that path means, that you have specified that path **wrong**. Since we don't know the absolute path of the file on **your machine**, we cannot help you in selecting proper value for `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property.